# Configure registry permission tool

Tags: windows, registry, permissions

I have to write a key value pair in the registry. This is done using a tool. This fails sometimes.

Is there any windows utility available which can set the permissions of the registry? If the specific user does not have permission to the registry, I should be able to configure the permissions accordingly - from an administrator account.

I have the only option of invoking it during system startup to set the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 bool flag1 = false;
            try
            {
                new System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert();
               // Your Work
            }
            catch (Exception obj1) //when (?)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission.RevertAssert();
            }
            return flag1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Regini.exe` tool. See here for more details: [How to change registry values or permissions from a command line or a script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264584)